# Поднятие строки таблицы по количеству совпадений

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица, с чекбоксами в ячейках, при нажатии на чекбокс в шапке таблицы, происходит поднятие строчки вверх, при нажатии на чекбокс другого столбца, происходит опять поднятие, но лесенкой. Но она работает с глюками, если выделить ве столбцы, то где больше совпадений, становиться все равно ниже, хотя должно быть выше всех строк. ПОмогите поправить

```js
var $table = $('table.tftable');
$table.on('change', '.chk-all', function() {
  var
    index = $(this).closest('td').index(),
    selector = `td:nth-child(${index + 1}) input[type="checkbox"]`,
    checked = this.checked;

  $table.find(`tr ${selector}`).prop('checked', checked);
  $table.find('tr').slice(1).filter(function() {
    return !$(this)
      .find('.black')
      .closest('td')
      .toArray()
      .map(n => $(n).index())
      .filter(n => n !== index)
      .filter(n => $table.find(`tr:first td:nth-child(${n + 1}) input:checked`).length).length;
  }).detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    var
      aGreen = $(a).find(selector).hasClass('black'),
      bGreen = $(b).find(selector).hasClass('black');

    return (bGreen ^ aGreen) ? [1, -1][+(checked ^ bGreen)] : 0;
  }).appendTo($table);
});
```

```css
.black {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tftable scroll" border="1">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="/uploads/logo.jpg" style="width: auto;height: auto;"></td>
      <td>
        <div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
          <div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
            <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/belaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Белая техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Белая техника" style="width: auto;height: auto;" data-original-title="Белая техника"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category71" class="chk-all">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
          <div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
            <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/vstroennaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Встроенная техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Встроенная техника" style="width: auto;height: auto;" data-original-title="Встроенная техника"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category72" class="chk-all">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
          <div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
            <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/klimaticheskaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Климатическая техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Климатическая техника" style="width: auto;height: auto;" data-original-title="Климатическая техника"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category73" class="chk-all">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
          <div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
            <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/melkaya-domashnyaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Мелкая домашняя техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Мелкая домашняя техника" style="width: auto;height: auto;" data-original-title="Мелкая домашняя техника"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category74" class="chk-all">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
          <div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
            <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/melkaya-kuhonnaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Мелкая кухонная техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Мелкая кухонная техника" style="width: auto;height: auto;" data-original-title="Мелкая кухонная техника"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category75" class="chk-all">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
          <div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
            <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/tehnika-dlya-krasoty/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Техника для красоты.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Техника для красоты" style="width: auto;height: auto;" data-original-title="Техника для красоты"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category76" class="chk-all">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="body-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/belaya-tehnika/17-sharp.html"><img src="/uploads/mini/215x70/42/a3e921a57b41f15ae50ccc8a63693b.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"></a><br>
        <span class="title">Шарп</span>
        <span class="adress">Степная 24</span>
        <span class="phone">*7 999 555 88 22</span>
        <a target="_blank" href="iuhbbhi.ru"><span class="site">iuhbbhi.ru</span></a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/belaya-tehnika/15-eychpi.html"><img src="/uploads/mini/215x70/4e/d14db65194e749a8c23b8b7d672f22.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"></a><br>
        <span class="title">ЭйчьПи</span>
        <span class="adress">Горького 52</span>
        <span class="phone">+7 908 500 500 8</span>
        <a target="_blank" href="iuhbbhi.ru"><span class="site">iuhbbhi.ru</span></a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/14-tehsnabeksport.html"><img src="/uploads/mini/215x70/13/56cb16d1cc7e18e234f61219252fc3.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"></a><br>
        <span class="title">Техснабэкспорт</span>
        <span class="adress">Гагарина 1</span>
        <span class="phone">+79526036525</span>
        <a target="_blank" href="pok.ru"><span class="site">pok.ru</span></a>

      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/vstroennaya-tehnika/13-hunter-industries.html"><img src="/uploads/mini/215x70/36/d1eff5c3c456b54f38105206fb68ea.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"></a><br>
        <span class="title">Hunter Industries</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
        <span class="phone">+79526036525</span>
        <a target="_blank" href="pok.ru"><span class="site">pok.ru</span></a>

      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/belaya-tehnika/12-ved-tranzit.html"><img src="/uploads/mini/215x70/00/eeb0659f8104578b33f862e51da0ff.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"></a><br>
        <span class="title">ВЭД ТРАНЗИТ</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
        <span class="phone">+79526036525</span>
        <a target="_blank" href="pok.ru"><span class="site">pok.ru</span></a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/belaya-tehnika/10-kompaniya-1.html"><img src="/uploads/mini/215x70/f8/40298d01d42642bb807f8966638fc1.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"></a><br>
        <span class="title">Компания #1</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
        <span class="phone">+79526036525</span>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://pokupatel.pro"><span class="site">http://pokupatel.pro</span></a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist">

      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
      <td>

        <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: я, если честно, не понял, что за поднятия, куда, и по какому принципу

Comment: Вот если нажать на чекбокс белой техники, идет поднятие строки выше всех, так как есть совпадение по классу black.

Comment: Мне нужно чем больше в строчке чекбоксов со стилем black, тем выше

Comment: вы в строку в `data`-атрибут запишите число своих `black` чекбоксов в строке, проще будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не знаю, такое вам что то надо или нет.
хтмл упростил несколько.

таблица сортируется в методе `update` при клике и в обычный чекбокс, и в `check-all`.

```js
// раскрасим ячейки по цветам
$(function(){
  $("input.black").closest('td').addClass('td-black');
  $("input.green").closest('td').addClass('td-green');
});

$(".chk-all").change(function(){
   var cIdx = $(this).closest('td').index();
   var sel  =  ".body-table tr td:nth-child(" +(cIdx + 1) +")";   
   
   $(sel).find("input")
         .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') );
   
   update();
});

$("tbody input").change(update);


function update(){
   var countBlacks = function(row){
                         return $(row).find("input.black:checked").length;
                     } 
                     
   var rows = $("tbody tr").get();
   rows.sort(function(a,b){
      return countBlacks(b) - countBlacks(a);
   }) ;
   
   $("tbody").append(rows);
}
```

```css
.td-black {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.td-green {
    background-color:rgba(0,255,0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tftable scroll" border="1">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category71" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category72" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category73" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category74" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category75" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category76" class="chk-all"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="body-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Шарп</span>
        <span class="adress">Степная 24</span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">ЭйчьПи</span>
        <span class="adress">Горького 52</span>        
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Техснабэкспорт</span>
        <span class="adress">Гагарина 1</span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Hunter Industries</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">ВЭД ТРАНЗИТ</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Компания #1</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: А можно еще сделать так, чтоб сама таблица обновлялась, если нет ни одной галочки в шапке? А то при снятии галочек, таблица не возвращается в исходное позицию

Comment: @Never3D надо сохранить исходный порядок строк куда нибудь в `data-` атрибут. и потом использовать его при сортировке, вместо подсчета классов

Comment: А скажите вы можете помочь? Пожалуйста.

Comment: @Never3D возможно, имеет смысл создать отдельный вопрос.  Поскольку это такая типовая задача по восстановлению исходного порядка сортировки и может быть полезна кому-то еще. а здесь ее найти сложно будет

Comment: Сделал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909109/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F