# Поднятие строки таблицы по количеству совпадений и возвращение в исходное состояние

Tags: jquery

таблица сортируется в методе update при клике и в обычный чекбокс, и в check-all.

```js
// раскрасим ячейки по цветам
$(function(){
  $("input.black").closest('td').addClass('td-black');
  $("input.green").closest('td').addClass('td-green');
});

$(".chk-all").change(function(){
   var cIdx = $(this).closest('td').index();
   var sel  =  ".body-table tr td:nth-child(" +(cIdx + 1) +")";   
   
   $(sel).find("input")
         .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') );
   
   update();
});

$("tbody input").change(update);


function update(){
   var countBlacks = function(row){
                         return $(row).find("input.black:checked").length;
                     } 
                     
   var rows = $("tbody tr").get();
   rows.sort(function(a,b){
      return countBlacks(b) - countBlacks(a);
   }) ;
   
   $("tbody").append(rows);
}
```

```css
.td-black {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.td-green {
    background-color:rgba(0,255,0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tftable scroll" border="1">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category71" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category72" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category73" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category74" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category75" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category76" class="chk-all"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="body-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Шарп</span>
        <span class="adress">Степная 24</span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">ЭйчьПи</span>
        <span class="adress">Горького 52</span>        
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Техснабэкспорт</span>
        <span class="adress">Гагарина 1</span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Hunter Industries</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">ВЭД ТРАНЗИТ</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="title">Компания #1</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

А можно еще сделать так, чтоб сама таблица обновлялась, если нет ни одной галочки в шапке? А то при снятии галочек, таблица не возвращается в исходное позицию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы иметь возможность восстановить исходный порядок сортировки, необходимо этот порядок где-либо сохранить. В данном случае простейший путь указания порядка - использования атрибутов строк: `<tr data-rn="1">`. Таким образом каждая строка будет хранить свой исходный  номер.

Далее ваша задача - при различных условиях использовать разные методы сортировки. Текущая реализация использует функцию подсчета чекнутых элементов `countBlacks`. Вам же в случае, когда ни один элемент не чекнут необходимо определить другую функцию, восстанавливающую исходный порядок. То есть фактически возвращающую сохраненный номер строки.

Таким образом, надо определить и вычислить само условие, а затем определить функцию (см. комменты в `update`):

```js
// раскрасим ячейки по цветам
$(function(){
  $("input.black").closest('td').addClass('td-black');
  $("input.green").closest('td').addClass('td-green');
});

$(".chk-all").change(function(){
   var cIdx = $(this).closest('td').index();
   var sel  =  ".body-table tr td:nth-child(" +(cIdx + 1) +")";   
   
   $(sel).find("input")
         .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') );
   
   update();
});

$("tbody input").change(update);


function update(){
   // есть ли отмеченные ячейки
   var checked = $("input:checked").length > 0;
   //изначально функция не определена
   var cmp = null; 

   // что то отмечено?  
   if(checked){
       //старая функция
       cmp = function(row){
                         return $(row).find("input.black:checked").length;
                     } 
   }
   else{
       // вернем исходный порядок
       cmp = function(row){ return -$(row).data("rn"); }
   }
                     
   var rows = $("tbody tr").get();
   rows.sort(function(a,b){
      return cmp(b) - cmp(a);  // и используем ее вместо старой countBlacks
   }) ;
   
   $("tbody").append(rows);
}
```

```css
.td-black {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.td-green {
    background-color:rgba(0,255,0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tftable scroll" border="1">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category71" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category72" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category73" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category74" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category75" class="chk-all"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category76" class="chk-all"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="body-table">
    <tr data-rn="1">
      <td>#1
        <span class="title">Шарп</span>
        <span class="adress">Степная 24</span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-rn="2">
      <td>#2
        <span class="title">ЭйчьПи</span>
        <span class="adress">Горького 52</span>        
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-rn="3">
      <td>#3
        <span class="title">Техснабэкспорт</span>
        <span class="adress">Гагарина 1</span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-rn="4">
      <td>#4
        <span class="title">Hunter Industries</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-rn="5">
      <td>#5
        <span class="title">ВЭД ТРАНЗИТ</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-rn="6">
      <td>#6
        <span class="title">Компания #1</span>
        <span class="adress"></span>
      </td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="black" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
      <td><input class="green" type="checkbox" name="catlist"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Возможно задача потребует некоторого изменения условия вычисления `checked`. Но в целом для подхода это не важно.

Comment: Единственное в чем проблема, так это таблица не статичная, т.е она постоянно меняется в зависимости от количества компаний. Т.е нужно data-rn="6" как то заменить на статическую цифру, так как изначально не ясно сколько будет tr с data-rn=""

Comment: @Never3D ну дак таблицу то вы генерите наверное средствами пхп или еще чего нибудь? там можете в цикле и пронумеровать ее, или что?

Comment: Да так и сделал, в php. Еще одн маленький вопрос. Как сделать чтоб по рейтингу выше были компании.
<p class="mrating8" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Покупательский рейтинг">8</p>
mrating8. 8 Это рейтинг.

Comment: @Never3D рейтинг тоже вывести в data-атарибут. и использовать при сортировке

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста правильный код. Это будет все) и Огромное ВАМ СПАСИБО

Comment: @Never3D ну выведите вы в строку `data-rating="1"` и т..п.  А в функции сравнения у вас если `cmp(a) == cmp(b)` то надо вернуть `$(a).data('rating') - $(b).data('rating')`.

Comment: Что-то не могу понять. Не работает

Comment: вместо `return cmp(a) - cmp(b);` будет `var r = cmp(a) - cmp(b); return r != 0 ? r : $(a).data('rating') - $(b).data('rating');`
но понятно что для варианта с сортировкой по исходному порядку не будет ситуации когда cmp совпадают, поскольку номера строк не повторяются.

Comment: Так понятно, но таблица перестала вообще сортировать по чекбосам)